# Set text as password with inputType="none"programatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on a custom numpad that set the text of specific Edittext by following way

```
myEditText .setText("myText");
```

But I want to set this text as password(Masked by ".") than normal text,I have set the

```
android:password="true"
```

and to prevent soft-keyboard from appearing on edittext focus

```
android:inputType="none"

myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

but still getting normal text in editttex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:inputType="textPassword"`

for example:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pwdTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"           
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=" Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >
        </EditText>
```

To Hide keyboard use below code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(getCurrentFocus()!=null)
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Will this not POP the android soft keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

use this in your `xml` :

```
<EditText
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>
```

or

```
edittext.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people who are having same problem. Just add an extra attribute to that EditText programmatically and you are done.

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Also, make sure that the cursor is at the end of the text in the edittext. Because, when you change the input type, the cursor will be automatically set to the starting point. So I'd rather suggest to use the following code.

```
et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
et_password.setSelection(et_password.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:hint=" none"` ,example :

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:hint=" none"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >
        </EditText>
```